# Could haxe macro be used to detect when object is dirty (any property has been changed)

Tags: haxe

Let say we have an object:

```
@:checkDirty
class Test {
   var a:Int;
   var b(default, default):String;
   var c(get, set):Array<Int>;

   public function new() {
     ...
   }
   public function get_c() {
      ...
   }
   public function set_c(n) {
     ... 
   }


}
```

Could we write a macro `checkDirty` so that any change to field/properties would set property `dirty` to `true`. Macro would generate `dirty` field as `Bool` and `clearDirty` function to set it to `false`.

```
var test = new Test();
trace(test.dirty); // false
test.a = 12;
trace(test.dirty); // true
test.clearDirty();
trace(test.dirty); //false
test.b = "test"
trace(test.dirty); //true

test.clearDirty();
test.c = [1,2,3];
trace(test.dirty); //true
```

Comment: You could, but that macro would have to transform everything into a `(get, set)` property.

Comment: @gama11 that is the idea, I'd like to have a macro write that code instead of me having to manually code each class, especially for simple DTO classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [a post](https://yal.cc/haxe-using-class-reification-in-build-macros/) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20210728085758/https://yal.cc/haxe-using-class-reification-in-build-macros/)) about doing this kind of thing (except for emitting events) before - you can use a `@:build` macro to modify class members, be it appending an extra assignment into setter or replacing the field with a property.

So a modified version might look like so:

```
class Macro {
    public static macro function build():Array<Field> {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        for (field in fields.copy()) { // (copy fields so that we don't go over freshly added ones)
            switch (field.kind) {
                case FVar(fieldType, fieldExpr), FProp("default", "default", fieldType, fieldExpr):
                    var fieldName = field.name;
                    if (fieldName == "dirty") continue;
                    var setterName = "set_" + fieldName;
                    var tmp_class = macro class {
                        public var $fieldName(default, set):$fieldType = $fieldExpr;
                        public function $setterName(v:$fieldType):$fieldType {
                            $i{fieldName} = v;
                            this.dirty = true;
                            return v;
                        }
                    };
                    for (mcf in tmp_class.fields) fields.push(mcf);
                    fields.remove(field);
                case FProp(_, "set", t, e):
                    var setter = Lambda.find(fields, (f) -> f.name == "set_" + field.name);
                    if (setter == null) continue;
                    switch (setter.kind) {
                        case FFun(f):
                            f.expr = macro { dirty = true; ${f.expr}; };
                        default:
                    }
                default:
            }
        }
        if (Lambda.find(fields, (f) -> f.name == "dirty") == null) fields.push((macro class {
            public var dirty:Bool = false;
        }).fields[0]);
        return fields;
    }
}
```

which, if used as

```
@:build(Macro.build())
@:keep class Some {
    public function new() {}
    public var one:Int;
    public var two(default, set):String;
    function set_two(v:String):String {
        two = v;
        return v;
    }
}
```

Would emit the following JS:

```js
var Some = function() {
    this.dirty = false;
};
Some.prototype = {
    set_two: function(v) {
        this.dirty = true;
        this.two = v;
        return v;
    }
    ,set_one: function(v) {
        this.one = v;
        this.dirty = true;
        return v;
    }
};
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted: 
https://try.haxe.org/#3899A7e1
Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work for the case below, will have to update the macro:
`public var three(default, default):Float;`

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen anyone use (default, default), but that can be addressed with an extra case matcher (edited the answer)

Comment: I actually found the issue on var field(default, null) but (default, default) was easier to demo.

Answer (score 2):

Just to note - whenever you consider proxying access to an object, in my experience, there are always hidden costs / added complexity. :)

That said, you have a few approaches:

First, if you want it to be pure Haxe, then either a macro or an abstract can get the job done. Either way, you're effectively transforming every property access into a function call that sets the value and also sets `dirty`.

For example, an abstract using the `@:resolve` getter and setter can be found in the [NME source code](https://github.com/haxenme/nme/blob/6ccbbdda7973090f304755f31964657c3f77650f/src/nme/net/URLVariables.hx#L99-L117), replicated here for convenience:

```
@:forward(decode,toString)
abstract URLVariables(URLVariablesBase)
{
   public function new(?inEncoded:String)
   {
      this = new URLVariablesBase(inEncoded);
   }
   @:resolve
   public function set(name:String, value:String) : String
   {
      return this.set(name,value);
   }

   @:resolve
   public function get(name:String):String
   {
      return this.get(name);
   }
}
```

This may be an older syntax, I'm not sure... also look at the [operator overloading examples](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-operator-overloading.html) on the Haxe manual:

```
  @:op(a.b) public function fieldRead(name:String)
    return this.indexOf(name);

  @:op(a.b) public function fieldWrite(name:String, value:String)
    return this.split(name).join(value);
```

Second, I'd just point out that if the underlying language / runtime supports some kind of Proxy object (e.g. [JavaScript Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)), and macro / abstract isn't working as expected, then you could build your functionality on top of that.